# Testing subscribe method in ngOnInit

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular8

I am testing subscribe in my angular component. My code is as follows.

```
      MyComponenet.ts
           ngOnInit() {
                getMyList();
               } 
        
          getMyList() {
             this.myService.getList().subscribe(resp => {
                  if (resp.length > 0) {
                    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
                  }
                }});

MyComponent.spec.ts - 

const data= [ {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "name 1",
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "name2",
  }
]

fdescribe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
  let myService: MyService


  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MyComponent],
      imports: [my imports...],
      providers: [MyService]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    myService= TestBed.get(MyService)
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('testing subscribe method calling', fakeAsync(() => {
    let listSpy = spyOn(myService, 'getList').and.returnValue(of(mockList))
    let subSpy = spyOn(myService.getList(), 'subscribe');
    component.ngOnInit();
    tick();
    expect(listSpy ).toHaveBeenCalledBefore(subSpy);
    expect(subSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }))

  it('test execution within subscribe method ', fakeAsync(() => {
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(component.dataSource).toBeDefined();
    expect(component.dataSource.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
  }))

});
```

I am getting following error on running second(test execution within subscribe method)  test case

```
Error: Expected undefined to be defined.
```

and in inspect element I am getting following

```
context.js:255 In Service error :  Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL: http://localhost:9876/undefinedgetList()
```

How can I resolve these errors and make my test case working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the actual service, mock it.

```
class MyMockService {
  getList = () => { return of(mockList)};
}
```

Next, you provide it in the spec.ts.

```
beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [ your declarations...],
    imports: [your imports...],
    // provide the component-under-test and dependent service
    providers: [
      ...
      { provide: MyService, useClass: MyMockService }
    ]
  });
});


it('test execution within subscribe method ', fakeAsync(() => {
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(component.dataSource).toBeDefined();
    expect(component.datasource).not.toBeNull();
  }))
});
```

Comment: where I need to put class MyMockService {
  getList = () => { return of(mockList)};
}  code? in same spec file itself? Is it possible for you to give a stackblitzz?

Comment: Sure. Please put your minimal code in a stackblitz, I can edit it and sent it back.

Comment: Yes, you put mock class in the same spec file before test class declaration. You can also put it in a separate file. it's up to you.

Comment: Drashti most of your suggestions are working. I am just getting error on " expect(component.dataSource.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);" line and the error is "Expected undefined to be greater than 0."

Comment: could you please guide me on this or if you can see any mistake in my above code

Comment: if I am using mockdata then how data will come in dataSource which will display data in table. I think I am wrong at that place but not sure

Comment: That is because you have initialized datasource as matTableDatasource object. It is not an array but an object. And hence it does not have length property.

Comment: what changes I need to do to make it compatible to MatTableDatasource?

Comment: yes you are right I removed MattableDatasource and it worked. But in my code I have to compulsorily use mattabledatasource. how can  I make it working with it?

Comment: If you want to check whether the datasource has been initalized then you can use expect(component.datasource).not.toBeNull() along with defined which you already did.

Comment: I want to check length of data source and if it is greater than zero then in my next test I will test the populated data in table

Comment: Try this : expect(component.dataSource.data.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);

Comment: Hey thanks it worked. I will accept your answer. Jus one last question if I want to use fileter in matDatatableSource as  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(resp.filter(item=> item.name.toLowerCase() == "david"));  it is giving me error as An error was thrown in afterAll Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined thrown. Any idea how can I resolve this?